# SonarQube 5.3 log: "Undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass" error messages

Tags: sonarqube, jruby

Why do I get this error message?

```
[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: ....
undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass
/web/WEB-INF/lib/authenticated_system.rb:132 in 'login_from_basic_auth'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290 in 'call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224 in 'call'
...
```

We have seen this error during rendering of different SonarQube "pages": /sessions/login and /api/qualityprofiles/export?language=cs&name=....&exportKey=resharper.cs and we could not reproduce this on an other environment. Looking in old postings we found several Ruby related hits on 'undefined method empty' but not connected with SonarQube.

Answer (score 2):

We saw the same error messages in our log after upgrading to SonarQube 5.4. Our Sonar instance is running behind an apache server that's acting as a reverse proxy. We're using basic authentication over https to add some additional security.

The solution in our case?

Add: `RequestHeader unset Authorization` in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` settings of our apache configuration.

This will strip out the Authorization header and prevents SonarQube from assuming we're doing an authentication request.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but more info to hopefully try and get an answer.

We have the same issue on login.  We have Sonar 5.3 and have had it running, then started to use the LDAP plugin.  We then removed the LDAP plugin from configuration and from the plugins directory and got this error every time on login.
We then created an empty database and still get the fault each time we try to log in.

Any idea how we can find out what is wrong with the installation and be able to log in as admin again?

The error text is here:

2016.03.03 16:56:54 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://:9000/sessions/login
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
D:/Program Files/SonarQube/web/WEB-INF/lib/authenticated_system.rb:132:in`login_from_basic_auth'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in`call'

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure out it?